# c# change color of sprites using a foreach loop

Tags: c#

Hi guys i am beginner in C# programming and I need someone to explain me how I can change the colors of sprites. One said me that i can do this using a `foreach` loop however I get the same color red color:

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Ionic.Zlib;

using Sulakore.Protocol;
using Sulakore.Extensions;

using Habbogram.Camera;
using Habbogram.Communication;

namespace Habbogram
{
    public partial class MainFrm : ExtensionForm
    {
        private const string PREVIEW_IMAGE_BASE_URL = "https://habbo-stories-content.s3.amazonaws.com/";

        private readonly Random _colorGenerator;

        private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _wasReplacedAwaitable;
        private readonly Action<HPhoto> _onCameraPayloadIntercepted;

        public CameraTriggers GramTriggers { get; }
        public HPhoto CurrentPhoto { get; private set; }
        public override bool IsExternal { get; } = true;

        public MainFrm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _colorGenerator = new Random();
            _wasReplacedAwaitable = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            _onCameraPayloadIntercepted = OnCameraPayloadIntercepted;

            GramTriggers = new CameraTriggers(true);
            GramTriggers.DetectIncoming = false;
            Triggers = GramTriggers;

            GramTriggers.CameraPayload += GramTriggers_CameraPayload;
        }

        private void UpdateInterface(HPhoto photo)
        {
            bool isReplacing = (photo != null);
            CancelBtn.Enabled = (ReplaceBtn.Enabled = isReplacing);

            PlanesTab.Text = $"Planes({photo?.Planes.Count ?? 0})";
            SpritesTab.Text = $"Sprites({photo?.Sprites.Count ?? 0})";
            FiltersTab.Text = $"Filters({photo?.Filters.Count ?? 0})";

            SpriteTxt.DataSource = photo?.Sprites;
            SpriteTxt.Enabled = (photo != null);
        }
        private Color GenerateRandomColor(byte alpha)
        {
            byte a = alpha;
            int r = _colorGenerator.Next(0, 126);
            int g = _colorGenerator.Next(0, 126);
            int b = _colorGenerator.Next(0, 126);

            return Color.FromArgb(alpha, r, g, b);
        }
        private void OnCameraPayloadIntercepted(HPhoto photo)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired) Invoke(_onCameraPayloadIntercepted, photo);
            else UpdateInterface(photo);
        }

        private void CancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _wasReplacedAwaitable.SetResult(false);
            UpdateInterface(null);
        }
        private void ReplaceBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _wasReplacedAwaitable.SetResult(true);
            UpdateInterface(null);
        }
        private void InterceptChckbx_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (InterceptChckbx.Checked)
            {
                GramTriggers.CameraPayload += GramTriggers_CameraPayload;
            }
            else
            {
                GramTriggers.CameraPayload -= GramTriggers_CameraPayload;
                UpdateInterface(null);
            }
        }
        private void GramTriggers_CameraPayload(object sender, CameraPayloadEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                e.ContinueRead();

                byte[] jsonPayload = ZlibStream.UncompressBuffer(e.JsonPayload);
                string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(jsonPayload);

                CurrentPhoto = HPhoto.Create(json);
                OnCameraPayloadIntercepted(CurrentPhoto);
                foreach (Camera.Layers.Sprite s in CurrentPhoto.Sprites)
                {
                    //Set color for all sprites in the photo.
                        s.Color = Color.FromArgb(1, 255, 1, 1).ToArgb();
                }

                // Wait for user to invoke a 'replace'.
                bool wasReplaced = _wasReplacedAwaitable.Task.Result;
                if (!wasReplaced) return; // User cancelled.

                json = CurrentPhoto.ToJson();

                byte[] compressedJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                compressedJson = ZlibStream.CompressBuffer(compressedJson);

                e.Replacement = new HMessage(e.Packet.Header,
                    compressedJson.Length, compressedJson);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Create new instance, so that we don't wait for an already completed task.
                _wasReplacedAwaitable = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `foreach` loop, you set the colour of each sprite to `argb(1, 255, 1, 1)`, which is red. The loop itself just iterates over the sprites. If you want to assign individual colours to each sprite, you must program it.

Comment: `s.Color = Color.FromArgb(1, 255, 1, 1).ToArgb();` always gives you red. I can't see a place in your code where your `GenerateRandomColor()` function is being used.

Comment: a ok how i can put individual colors to each sprite? And how i can change the red color to the other color? this is my question maybe i dont explain very well my problem sorry

Comment: Maxi i have one file about generaterandomcolor i think this is the key or not?

Comment: You need to find the place in code where you want to change the colors (maybe at the beginning, not in some camera handler?) then do `s.Color = GenerateRandomColor().ToArgb();` on each `Sprite s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgot to use call GenerateRandomColor() function. You can either call that function inside foreach loop or simply copy following code and paste it at place of your foreach loop. Upvote this answer if it satisfies.

```
foreach (Camera.Layers.Sprite s in CurrentPhoto.Sprites)
{
   s.Color = Color.FromArgb(1, _colorGenerator.Next(1,256), _colorGenerator.Next(1,256), _colorGenerator.Next(1,256));
}
```

Also it seems that s.Color takes Color datatype...so you don't need to use .ToArgb(). However, if it does take int value, then do add .ToArgb() in the end of code.